# Displaying .div or images in this order

Tags: html, css

How to position something in this order.
This is what I want to achieve
[image]

And this is what I have now
[image]

Could someone explain to me how do i move this upwards nicely and in order?

```
            <div class="middle">
            <div id="middletop">
                <img style="padding-left: 5px;padding-top:6px;" src="img/slider.png"/>
                    <a href="" class="downloadbutton" title="Pobierz grę"></a>
                    <a href="" class="signbutton" title="Zarejestruj się"></a>
                    <div class="channels">
                        <img src="img/status.png"/></br>
                        <img src="img/status.png"/></br>
                        <img src="img/status.png"/></br>
                        <img src="img/status.png"/>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS code

```
.middle
{
   background: url('../img/middlebg.png') no-repeat center;
   width: 1009px;
   margin-top: 370px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   height: 1536px;
   position: relative;
}

#middletop {
   display: absolute;

}
.downloadbutton {
   background: url('../img/download.png') top no-repeat;
   width: 198px;
   height: 67px;
   display: inline-block;
}.downloadbutton:hover {
   background: url('../img/download_hover.png') top no-repeat;
}
.signbutton {
   background: url('../img/sign.png') top no-repeat;
   width: 122px;
   height: 67px;
   display: inline-block;
}
.signbutton:hover {
   background: url('../img/sign_hover.png') top no-repeat;
}

.channels {
}
```

Comment: Hi p0na and welcome! Have you worked through sites like w3schools or FreeCodeCamp to try and solve this on your own? By working through either of these you should be able to answer this on your own. Once you do, answering your own question here is encouraged.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to vertically align an image inside a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div)

Comment: Please don't recycle questions. Ask a new one instead.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example you've given us I was able to create a layout that is easy to use and (hopefully) understand.

#### The layout

I've used tables to create a grid. This way you won't have to think about the use of position, because every element inside the grid will be placed automatically.

```
<body>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="container">
            <div id="slider">Slider</div>
        </td>
        <td class="container">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button id="button1">button1</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="button2">button2</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <input placeholder="something1" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <input placeholder="something2" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <input placeholder="something3" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

</body>
```

#### Styling

```
        table {
          border-collapse: collapse;
          width: 100%;
          border: none;
        }

        td, tr {
          border: 1px solid #dddddd;
          text-align: left;
          padding: 8px;
        }

        table,
        td, tr {
            border: none;
        }

        td {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .container {
            width: 50%;
        }

        #slider {
            width: 90%;
            height: 150px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        input {
            width: 90%;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

css code,

```
.middle
    {
       background: url('../img/middlebg.png') no-repeat center;
       width: 1009px;
       /*margin-top: 370px;*/
       margin-left: auto;
       margin-right: auto;
       height: 1536px;
       position: relative;
    }

    #middletop {
       display: absolute;

    }
    #middletop > img {
       float: left;
    }
    .downloadbutton {
       background: url('../img/download.png') top no-repeat;
       /*width: 198px;*/
       height: 67px;
       display: inline-block;
    }
    .downloadbutton:hover {
       background: url('../img/download_hover.png') top no-repeat;
    }
    .signbutton {
       background: url('../img/sign.png') top no-repeat;
       width: 122px;
       height: 67px;
       display: inline-block;
    }
    .signbutton:hover {
       background: url('../img/sign_hover.png') top no-repeat;
    }

    .inline-block{
        display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .inline-block a{
        flex: 0 0 50%;;
    }
```

html code

```
<div class="middle">
<div id="middletop">
    <img style="padding-left: 5px;padding-top:6px;" src="img/slider.png"/>
    <div class="inline-block">
        <a href="" class="downloadbutton" title="Pobierz grę">btn 1</a>
        <a href="" class="signbutton" title="Zarejestruj się">btn 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="channels">
        <div>some 1</div>
        <div>some 2</div>
        <div>some 3</div>
        <div>some 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```